# Block incoming connections with hostnames that contain IP addresses

Tags: postfix-mta, spam-prevention

I used to run `qmail` with `spamdyke`, and `spamdyke` has a nifty ability to block incoming mail if the host looks like these:

```
static-68-179-34-50.ptr.terago.net
c-75-74-22-18.hsd1.fl.comcast.net
173-14-159-121-newengland.hfc.comcastbusiness.net
rrcs-24-43-130-226.west.biz.rr.com
va-65-40-217-136.sta.embarqhsd.net
unused-66-33-224-181.unused.epix.net
c-67-190-66-10.hsd1.co.comcast.net
```

Basically, it had some form of the IP addres in the hostname, which usually designates dynamic clients, et cetera.
Since they have no reason to try to send mail directly to my SMTP server, they can be considered spammers with 99.99% certainty.

What is the easiest way to achieve same functionality with `postfix`?

http://www.spamdyke.org/documentation/README.html#RDNS

Answer (score 2):

Usually its safer to use the [spamhaus PBL](http://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/), but you can do this with

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname,  check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/helo.regexp
```

in the helo.regexp add

```
/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+[.-@]/  REJECT
```

You can fine tune it if you want, or use PCRE instead (dont forget to update the format in the smtpd_helo_restrictions line)

Comment: Can i have it checking with multiple regexes per line, or do they have to be incorporated into one regex, or 1 per file?

Comment: multiple are OK, just add whatever you need. You can also add first some regexp with OK - to whitelist - or DUNNO - to ignore the rest of this file and avoid blocking by the remaining rules. Then add the reject lines to reject whatever match then and that didn't match the previous rules. Check the [postfix access man page](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html)